# function parameters not retained using Arc?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

**EDIT**: This is for a static NSMutableDictionary, not a class member. I see a lot of answers thinking it's a class member, sorry about that. Thanks for the quick responses.

I had a working piece of code, but it was used 2x, so I wrote a convenience function:

```
- (void) initializeDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*)mutableDict fromPathName:(NSString*)path
{ 
     mutableDict = // get from file, init if not there.
}
```

Then I noticed nothing was saving. Stepping through the code, the function creates a dictionary, but the "passed in" value is still nil upon returning. This completely blows away my understanding of pointers (don't take this the wrong way, I'm very comfortable). But their purpose, I thought, was to let you "pass the address" so I could hydrate the thing it points to.

since mutableDict is the "value copy", ARC appears to be wiping it out. I'm asking here because

1. the other questions have the opposite question "Why is this being retained?" and
2. It doesn't seem right. Your very first tutorial in any pointer language is "so you can mess with the original value". Does Arc really do this? Is there a concept I'm not getting?

And of course, I may be overlooking something simple.

I seem to have solved it by doing the writeback trick I found elsewhere:

```
- (void) initializeDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary* __strong *)mutableDictionary fromPath:(NSString*)path;
```

and using the & to call and * deref to change the value. It just seems far less than elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a pointer of `NSDictionary`. If you change the pointer value of `mutableDict` (by allocation or assignment) this will NOT be reflected on the variable passed as this function's argument and since mutableDict is locally defined in the function it will be released by `ARC` automatically. (Do not forget that even for pointers the address is copied when passed to a function).

The reason that your second solution works is because you pass a pointer to a pointer (not sure if strong is needed there). The value of `*mutableDict` will be reflected outside since you update a value in the address pointed to by `mutableDict`. This value is the address of your allocated dictionary and since you change it via a pointer it will be reflected outside the function.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid, somehow forgot objective C's syntax is clean and masks the autodereference. I'll get comfortable with ARC as I go along... just avoided it for awhile since I do Core stuff.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want you use multiple indirection

```
- (void) initializeDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary**)mutableDict fromPathName:(NSString*)path
{ 
     mutableDict = // get from file, init if not there.
}
```

Notice the parameter is (NSMutableDictionary **), a pointer to a pointer to an NSMutableDictionary.

To call the method you need to create a pointer and pass it in like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary;
[self initializeDictionary: &mutableDictionary fromPathName:...];
```

And on return, the `mutableDictionary` variable will have been initialised by the method.

However, It's probably easier to just return the dictionary from the method rather than doing it this way.

Comment: My last code snippet shows that's how I'm doing it... my question was if that was the only way, since it makes basic operations complicated. We're not conforming to a language, we're conforming to ARC not understanding.

Comment: Ah, I just remembered, Objective C's pointers are auto-dereferenced nearly since the syntax of [] handles the messaging stuff. Gah, I knew that'd get me some day. Thanks.

Comment: It's a very common way of doing it. There is even a naming convention that says such methods should start with `get`, have a look at the methods in `UIColor` that do this to initialize `r`, `g`, `b` values by reference. It's overcomplicated here, because it's better (IMHO) to  just write a method that returns a single initialised value from the method.

Comment: Yeah, I may just rewrite stuff in the future that way. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C if you define a variable in a method, the variable is visible only in that method.

If you need to save the variable to use it outside, you need to "return" it from your function. What you did wasn't a trick, is another way of returning a variable.

Try with:

```
- (void)initializeDictionaryFromPath:(NSString*)path {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = // your initialization 
    return mutableDict;
}
```

Then you can define your dictionary with this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [self initializeDictionaryFromPath:path];
```